# Play Framework 2.3.x SBT config for github Javascript repos

Tags: playframework, sbt

Anyone figure out a way to configure SBT to pull in a Javascript library from a github repo?  I realize you can use webjars.org, but I'd like to pull from a github repo directly.  I can do this with bower - anyone figure it out how to do this with libraryDependencies config?